# How to prevent GSAP typewriting animation to stagger up on every line?

Tags: css, animation, gsap

I have a typewriter animation for a h1 text. This h1 element is centered in a div using `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle`. The div itself has `display: table`.

When my GSAP animation fires up, the height of the h1 is not final; it grows in size as the typing animation goes on until it reaches its final size. This causes a problem where you can visually see the text stagger up for each line of text that is written, like this:

[image]

Like the gif shows, it staggers up for every new line the typewriter writes. I realize that it is because my text is vertically centered that it reajusts itself like that each time, but I would like it to be the final size from the get-go, so you do not see this staggering happening. Any ideas?

Here's the code for my typewriting animation, just in case it is needed. Also I'm new at GSAP, so any feedback is appreciated.

```
 // typewriter animation
 gsap.to('.cursor', {
    duration: 1,
    opacity: 0, 
    ease: "power2.inOut", 
    repeat: -1,
 });

 let sentence = document.querySelector(".data").innerHTML;

 let timelineText = gsap.timeline();

 timelineText.to('.text', {
    duration: 7,
    text: sentence
 });

 timelineText.delay(1);
```